# Make heatmap more similar to excel one

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to take a [list of lists](https://pastebin.com/ayxBVFuG) and create a heatmap using the first column as the column labels, the second as the row labels and the fourth as the values. I want the heatmap to look closer to this one:
[image]

This is the closest I've got:
[image]

I haven't been able to use the data from my list because I don't know how to get it to the format needed.

I haven't been able to add the red and yellows, it all looks like greens.

And the highlight isn't working properly, the max and min value aren't actually correct.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sb
import numpy as np

from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

row_labels = np.random.rand(25)
col_labels = np.random.rand(10)
data = np.random.rand(25, 10)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=col_labels, index=row_labels)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 9), facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
ax = sb.heatmap(data, xticklabels=col_labels, yticklabels=row_labels,
                      cmap='RdYlGn', cbar=False, center=0.00, annot=True,
                      fmt ='0.2f', ax=ax)

# Highlight max and min values
ymax = max(df)
xmax = df.index.get_loc(df[ymax].idxmax())
ax.add_patch(Rectangle((ymax,xmax),1,1, fill=False, edgecolor='blue', lw=3))

ymin = min(df)
xmin = df.index.get_loc(df[ymin].idxmin())
ax.add_patch(Rectangle((ymin,xmin),1,1, fill=False, edgecolor='blue', lw=3))

ax.set_title('Annualized Returns (%)', fontsize=12, color='black', fontweight="bold")
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=10, labelbottom = False, bottom=False, top = False, labeltop=True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second plot doesn't have red because of the `center=0.0`. This puts all the green values for positive numbers up till the largest value encountered, and red for the negatives. As there aren't any negatives, no red is shown.

To work with numeric data, things are much easier to work with when the lists are converted to numpy arrays.  The code example below uses the unique values of the first column as y-labels, the second column as x-labels and the fourth column as values.

To replace the standard 'RdYlGn' colormap, a new colormap is created with a list of some brighter colors. As the dataset only contains 6 different values, the heatmap looks quite uniform.

The position where the minimum and maximum values occur a first time can be found using `np.argmin()` and `np.argmax()`. Setting `clip_on=False` prevents that the sides of the rectangle that coincide with the heatmap border would be clipped away partly.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

data = [[8, 38, 325780.56, 7.66], [8, 39, 325774.92, 7.67], [8, 40, 325774.92, 7.67], [8, 41, 325774.92, 7.67], [8, 42, 325774.92, 7.67], [8, 43, 325774.92, 7.67], [8, 44, 325774.92, 7.67], [8, 45, 325774.92, 7.67], [8, 46, 325774.92, 7.67], [8, 47, 294428.96, 7.51], [8, 48, 294428.96, 7.51], [8, 49, 294428.96, 7.51], [8, 50, 294428.96, 7.51], [9, 38, 325774.92, 7.67], [9, 39, 325774.92, 7.67], [9, 40, 325774.92, 7.67], [9, 41, 325774.92, 7.67], [9, 42, 325774.92, 7.67], [9, 43, 325774.92, 7.67], [9, 44, 325774.92, 7.67], [9, 45, 325774.92, 7.67], [9, 46, 325774.92, 7.67], [9, 47, 294428.96, 7.51], [9, 48, 294428.96, 7.51], [9, 49, 294428.96, 7.51], [9, 50, 294428.96, 7.51], [10, 38, 325774.92, 7.67], [10, 39, 325774.92, 7.67], [10, 40, 318816.85, 7.63], [10, 41, 318816.85, 7.63], [10, 42, 318816.85, 7.63], [10, 43, 318816.85, 7.63], [10, 44, 318816.85, 7.63], [10, 45, 318816.85, 7.63], [10, 46, 325774.92, 7.67], [10, 47, 294431.51, 7.51], [10, 48, 294431.51, 7.51], [10, 49, 294431.51, 7.51], [10, 50, 294431.51, 7.51], [11, 38, 318816.85, 7.63], [11, 39, 318816.85, 7.63], [11, 40, 318816.85, 7.63], [11, 41, 318816.85, 7.63], [11, 42, 318816.85, 7.63], [11, 43, 318816.85, 7.63], [11, 44, 318816.85, 7.63], [11, 45, 318816.85, 7.63], [11, 46, 318816.85, 7.63], [11, 47, 318816.85, 7.63], [11, 48, 294431.51, 7.51], [11, 49, 294431.51, 7.51], [11, 50, 294431.51, 7.51], [12, 38, 318816.85, 7.63], [12, 39, 318816.85, 7.63], [12, 40, 318816.85, 7.63], [12, 41, 318816.85, 7.63], [12, 42, 318816.85, 7.63], [12, 43, 318816.85, 7.63], [12, 44, 318816.85, 7.63], [12, 45, 318816.85, 7.63], [12, 46, 318816.85, 7.63], [12, 47, 318816.85, 7.63], [12, 48, 294428.11, 7.52], [12, 49, 294428.11, 7.52], [12, 50, 294428.11, 7.52], [13, 38, 318816.85, 7.63], [13, 39, 318816.85, 7.63], [13, 40, 318816.85, 7.63], [13, 41, 318816.85, 7.63], [13, 42, 318816.85, 7.63], [13, 43, 318816.85, 7.63], [13, 44, 318816.85, 7.63], [13, 45, 318816.85, 7.63], [13, 46, 318816.85, 7.63], [13, 47, 318816.85, 7.63], [13, 48, 294428.11, 7.52], [13, 49, 294428.11, 7.52], [13, 50, 294428.11, 7.52], [14, 38, 318816.85, 7.63], [14, 39, 318816.85, 7.63], [14, 40, 318816.85, 7.63], [14, 41, 318816.85, 7.63], [14, 42, 318816.85, 7.63], [14, 43, 318816.85, 7.63], [14, 44, 318816.85, 7.63], [14, 45, 318816.85, 7.63], [14, 46, 318816.85, 7.63], [14, 47, 318816.85, 7.63], [14, 48, 294428.11, 7.52], [14, 49, 294428.11, 7.52], [14, 50, 294428.11, 7.52], [15, 38, 318816.85, 7.63], [15, 39, 318816.85, 7.63], [15, 40, 318816.85, 7.63], [15, 41, 318810.41, 7.63], [15, 42, 318810.41, 7.63], [15, 43, 318810.41, 7.63], [15, 44, 318810.41, 7.63], [15, 45, 318816.85, 7.63], [15, 46, 318816.85, 7.63], [15, 47, 318816.85, 7.63], [15, 48, 294428.11, 7.52], [15, 49, 294428.11, 7.52], [15, 50, 294428.11, 7.52], [16, 38, 318816.85, 7.63], [16, 39, 318810.41, 7.63], [16, 40, 318810.41, 7.63], [16, 41, 318810.41, 7.63], [16, 42, 318810.41, 7.63], [16, 43, 318810.41, 7.63], [16, 44, 318810.41, 7.63], [16, 45, 318810.41, 7.63], [16, 46, 318816.85, 7.63], [16, 47, 318816.85, 7.63], [16, 48, 294428.11, 7.52], [16, 49, 294428.11, 7.52], [16, 50, 294428.11, 7.52], [17, 38, 318810.41, 7.63], [17, 39, 318810.41, 7.63], [17, 40, 318810.41, 7.63], [17, 41, 318810.41, 7.63], [17, 42, 318810.41, 7.63], [17, 43, 318810.41, 7.63], [17, 44, 318810.41, 7.63], [17, 45, 318810.41, 7.63], [17, 46, 318810.41, 7.63], [17, 47, 318816.85, 7.63], [17, 48, 294431.51, 7.51], [17, 49, 294431.51, 7.51], [17, 50, 294428.11, 7.52], [18, 38, 318810.41, 7.63], [18, 39, 318810.41, 7.63], [18, 40, 318810.41, 7.63], [18, 41, 318810.41, 7.63], [18, 42, 318810.41, 7.63], [18, 43, 318810.41, 7.63], [18, 44, 318810.41, 7.63], [18, 45, 318810.41, 7.63], [18, 46, 318810.41, 7.63], [18, 47, 318810.41, 7.63], [18, 48, 294431.51, 7.51], [18, 49, 294431.51, 7.51], [18, 50, 294431.51, 7.51], [19, 38, 318810.41, 7.63], [19, 39, 318810.41, 7.63], [19, 40, 318810.41, 7.63], [19, 41, 318810.41, 7.63], [19, 42, 318810.41, 7.63], [19, 43, 318810.41, 7.63], [19, 44, 318810.41, 7.63], [19, 45, 318810.41, 7.63], [19, 46, 318810.41, 7.63], [19, 47, 318810.41, 7.63], [19, 48, 294431.51, 7.51], [19, 49, 294431.51, 7.51], [19, 50, 294431.51, 7.51], [20, 38, 318810.41, 7.63], [20, 39, 318810.41, 7.63], [20, 40, 318810.41, 7.63], [20, 41, 318817.77, 7.62], [20, 42, 318817.77, 7.62], [20, 43, 318817.77, 7.62], [20, 44, 318810.41, 7.63], [20, 45, 318810.41, 7.63], [20, 46, 318810.41, 7.63], [20, 47, 318810.41, 7.63], [20, 48, 318810.41, 7.63], [20, 49, 294431.51, 7.51], [20, 50, 294431.51, 7.51], [21, 38, 318810.41, 7.63], [21, 39, 318817.77, 7.62], [21, 40, 318817.77, 7.62], [21, 41, 318817.77, 7.62], [21, 42, 318817.77, 7.62], [21, 43, 318817.77, 7.62], [21, 44, 318817.77, 7.62], [21, 45, 318810.41, 7.63], [21, 46, 318810.41, 7.63], [21, 47, 318810.41, 7.63], [21, 48, 318810.41, 7.63], [21, 49, 294431.51, 7.51], [21, 50, 294431.51, 7.51], [22, 38, 318817.77, 7.62], [22, 39, 318817.77, 7.62], [22, 40, 318817.77, 7.62], [22, 41, 318817.77, 7.62], [22, 42, 318817.77, 7.62], [22, 43, 318817.77, 7.62], [22, 44, 318817.77, 7.62], [22, 45, 318817.77, 7.62], [22, 46, 318810.41, 7.63], [22, 47, 318810.41, 7.63], [22, 48, 318810.41, 7.63], [22, 49, 294432.36, 7.51], [22, 50, 294431.51, 7.51], [23, 38, 318817.77, 7.62], [23, 39, 318817.77, 7.62], [23, 40, 318817.77, 7.62], [23, 41, 318817.77, 7.62], [23, 42, 318817.77, 7.62], [23, 43, 318817.77, 7.62], [23, 44, 318817.77, 7.62], [23, 45, 318817.77, 7.62], [23, 46, 318817.77, 7.62], [23, 47, 318810.41, 7.63], [23, 48, 318810.41, 7.63], [23, 49, 294432.36, 7.51], [23, 50, 294432.36, 7.51], [24, 38, 318817.77, 7.62], [24, 39, 318817.77, 7.62], [24, 40, 318816.85, 7.63], [24, 41, 318816.85, 7.63], [24, 42, 318816.85, 7.63], [24, 43, 318816.85, 7.63], [24, 44, 318817.77, 7.62], [24, 45, 318817.77, 7.62], [24, 46, 318817.77, 7.62], [24, 47, 318810.41, 7.63], [24, 48, 318810.41, 7.63], [24, 49, 294432.36, 7.51], [24, 50, 294432.36, 7.51], [25, 38, 318817.77, 7.62], [25, 39, 318816.85, 7.63], [25, 40, 318816.85, 7.63], [25, 41, 318816.85, 7.63], [25, 42, 318816.85, 7.63], [25, 43, 318816.85, 7.63], [25, 44, 318816.85, 7.63], [25, 45, 318817.77, 7.62], [25, 46, 318817.77, 7.62], [25, 47, 318817.77, 7.62], [25, 48, 318810.41, 7.63], [25, 49, 294432.36, 7.51], [25, 50, 294432.36, 7.51]]
data = np.array(data)
xs = np.unique(data[:, 1].astype(int))
ys = np.unique(data[:, 0].astype(int))
vals = data[:, 3].reshape(len(ys), len(xs))
min_val_ndx = np.unravel_index(np.argmin(vals, axis=None), vals.shape)
max_val_ndx = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(vals, axis=None), vals.shape)

cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('', ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'chartreuse', 'limegreen'])
ax = sns.heatmap(vals, xticklabels=xs, yticklabels=ys, cmap=cmap, annot=True, fmt='.2f')

ax.add_patch(Rectangle(min_val_ndx[::-1], 1, 1, fill=False, edgecolor='blue', lw=3, clip_on=False))
ax.add_patch(Rectangle(max_val_ndx[::-1], 1, 1, fill=False, edgecolor='blue', lw=3, clip_on=False))

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]